# Trying to create dataframe with two columns [Seq(), String] - Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

When I run the following on the spark-shell, I get a dataframe:

```
scala> val df = Seq(Array(1,2)).toDF("a")

scala> df.show(false)
+------+
|a     |
+------+
|[1, 2]|
+------+
```

But when I run the following to create a dataframe with two columns:

```
scala> val df1 = Seq(Seq(Array(1,2)),"jf").toDF("a","b")
<console>:23: error: value toDF is not a member of Seq[Object]
    val df1 = Seq(Seq(Array(1,2)),"jf").toDF("a","b")
```

I get the error:

> Value toDF is not a member of Seq[Object].

How do I go about this? Is toDF only supported for sequences with primitive datatypes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need a `Seq` of `Tuple` for the `toDF` method to work:

```
val df1 = Seq((Array(1,2),"jf")).toDF("a","b")
// df1: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [a: array<int>, b: string]

df1.show
+------+---+
|     a|  b|
+------+---+
|[1, 2]| jf|
+------+---+
```

Add more tuples for more rows:

```
val df1 = Seq((Array(1,2),"jf"), (Array(2), "ab")).toDF("a","b")
// df1: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [a: array<int>, b: string]

df1.show
+------+---+
|     a|  b|
+------+---+
|[1, 2]| jf|
|   [2]| ab|
+------+---+
```

Comment: Thanks it helped! So I was wrong when I created a Sequence(Array[Int], String), a tuple supports different kinds, a sequence doesn't, if I'm correct.

Comment: I got the same error. "value toDF is not a member of Seq[Array[String]]" Any suggestion?

Comment: Late reply but `import spark.implicits._`